# How to change the color of the tray

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

On Xubuntu, I have everything set to the color I want, but this. How do I change the color of that part?

[image]

Comment: Is that really the Xubuntu indicator plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Initially my Indicator Plugin was a different color from the rest of the panel. However, I corrected this by going to Appearance in Panel settings. I toggled on None (use system style). Then I selected Solid color. After that the Indicator Plugin matched the background of everything else on the panel. I am using Xubuntu 14.04 with Xfce 4.12 installed via PPA.